# How can I access C folder in power shell?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, ubuntu, command-prompt

I have very simple problem with approaching C drive in Ubuntu 20.04.3 on my personal computer.

I'm using command following:

```
cd \home\C:
```

But I get error: `bash: cd: homeC:: No such file or directory`

Do you know which command should be used to do so?

Comment: Is the Ubuntu installation a WSL guest? If so, the path you're looking for is probably `/mnt/c`

Comment: So you are on Windows and you are running the Windows subsystem for linux?

Comment: I tried `cd /home/mnt/c` but it says `No such file or directory`

Comment: This question is off topic for Stack Overflow as it has nothing to do with programming. You may consider asking this question over on [su]

Answer (score 1):

First check your mointing points, using the `mount` function. In case of a Windows subsystem for Linux you might have something like this:

```
C:\ on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
D:\ on /mnt/d type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)
```

The part `on /mnt/c` (can be different in your case, obviously), shows the actual Linux folder. Please keep in mind that Linux is case sensitive.